# Запятая или другой знак?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

*Впрочем, река в этой низине повсюду **напоминала о своем присутствии**, просачивалась сквозь травяной покров, облизывала поля* (О. Токарчук).

Здесь вроде бы явное обобщение, но стоит запятая. Почему бы не поставить тире или двоеточие? Или достаточно запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [предыдущее предложение](http://knignaja-tarelka.blogspot.com/2016/03/blog-post_17.html).

> Прошла весь парк, а потом — проселочными дорогами, через кукурузу и влажные луга, усыпанные калужницей, нарезанные на квадраты мелиорационными канавами, — добралась до самой реки.

В нем автор уже дала определенную характеристику местности: влажные луга; калужница, которая растет вдоль водоемов и в заболоченных местах; мелиорационные канавы — признак осушения земель.

В нашем же предложении автору уже не нужно, как мне кажется, ничего обобщать — все глаголы «одного уровня» и нестандартно («завершающе») описывают увиденную картину. Теоретически их можно даже «поменять» на деепричастия — *просачиваясь, облизывая* (как добавочное действие).

Вопрос о постановке тире или двоеточия встал бы при другой структуре предложения (но автор, думаю, старательно избегал такого восприятия).

*Впрочем, река в этой низине напоминала о своем присутствии **повсюду: (—)** просачивалась сквозь травяной покров, облизывала поля.*

Comment: Римма, спасибо большое за ответ, вы здесь самый внимательный и любящий читатель художественной литературы. Я, как ни старалась, не могу не видеть смысловых нарушений при оформлении однородных членов. Но я могу понять желание автора использовать перечисление глаголов (ударение в этом случае ставится на глаголы): Впрочем, река в этой низине повсюду напоминАла о своем присутствии, просачивалась сквозь травяной покрОв, облИзывала поля. Но  читатель может этого сразу не увидеть  и поставить ударение на "повсЮду", а тогда это обобщение. Я вот думаю: может быть, надо было заменить на "постоянно".

Comment: Ну-у, особым книгочейством я, конечно же, не отличаюсь. А за добрые слова кланяюсь — премного благодарна. По поводу "постоянно" (неизменно, непрерывно, регулярно) — это ведь временное наречие. Автор ничего не говорит о разных периодах (утро, день,  месяц, времена года), использует только **пространственные** обозначения: повсюду — в любом месте, везде, повсеместно. Мне кажется, что "постоянно" не подходит.

Comment: Римма, я Вас благодарю за любовь к русскому языку, потому что люди на подобных форумах себя в языке иногда любят больше, чем сам язык. И что очень грустно, наши многие "бескорыстные" любители или совсем ушли, или работают очень мало. Теперь по поводу наречия. В книге ребенок первый раз шел к реке, он ее еще не видел, но признаки близкой воды попадались на пути. Постоянно - это как бы за то время, пока он туда шел.

Answer (score 1):

Автор не считает "просачивалась" и "облизывала" примерами напоминания о своём присутствии. У него все три глагола равноправны. Имеет право, но это не логично.

Я бы тире поставил, так как объясняется значение фразы "напоминала о своем присутствии".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что автор имел право на такое оформление и убедил редакторов с корректорами. Обобщение (через тире) или раскрытие (двоеточие) означало бы, что присутствие реки выражалось лишь в мелких и косвенных проявлениях, в то время как "везде" подразумевает и открытые виды на реку в других местах низины или с других ракурсов. Можно было бы после проблемной запятой добавить "например", "даже" или "в частности", но это сделало бы текст излишне формальным по стилю (какой-нибудь современный журналист и вовсе вставил бы здесь убогое для такого контекста "в том числе"). Поэтому автор предпочёл добавить уточняющие примеры через запятую, опустив присоедительное слово.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение. Подробнее я написала в комментарии для Риммы.